# How to remove the boilerplate code when using q in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, q, boilerplate

I am currently using [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) with `Node.js`. All my models use the promises from `q`. Later I realized writing a lot of boilerplate code like this

```
count: function(){
  var deferred = Q.defer()
  User.count(function(err,count){
    if(err)
      deferred.reject(err)
    else
      deferred.resolve(count)
  })
  return deferred.promise;
},
findAll: function(){
  var deferred = Q.defer()
  User.find({}, function(err,users){
    if(err)
      deferred.reject(err)
    else
      deferred.resolve(users)
  })
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Is there a way remove this boilerplate code?

Comment: can you provide sample `User.count` and `User.find`?

Comment: @Grundy, I use mongoose, hence they are default mongoose model methods.

Comment: seems mongoose implement using promises: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#promise_Promise

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec

Comment: deprecated just using some implementation, but `exec` function still return _promise_. Now return **native** Promise

Comment: so, seems your code should be like this: `count: function(){
  return User.count().exec(); }, findAll: function(){
  return User.find({}).exec();}`

Comment: @Grundy, Works great. Thanks. I can use this for all Mongoose related promises.

Comment: FYI, the "plain" mongodb bindings for node.js also return native Promises if you don't pass a callback function.

Comment: @Rahul: Up to you, but FWIW I'd mark Bergi's answer rather than mine as the answer. If you do, ping me with an @ if you would and I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way remove this boilerplate code?

Yes, Q has [dedicated helper functions for interfacing with node callbacks](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#interfacing-with-nodejs-callbacks).

You can simplify your code to

```
count: function(){
  return Q.nfcall(User.count);
},
findAll: function(){
  return Q.nfcall(User.find, {});
}
```

If those methods rely on their `this` value, you can use `Q.ninvoke(User, "count")` and `Q.ninvoke(User, "find", {})`.

You can even take this to a higher extreme and avoid the function expression completely, by using Q's function/method binding:

```
count: Q.nfbind(User.count),
findAll: Q.nfbind(User.find, {})
```

or with a `this` value:

```
count: Q.nbind(User.count, User),
findAll: Q.nbind(User.find, User, {})
```

But notice that with these solutions you need to ensure that `count` and `findAll` are called with zero arguments.

Comment: I *should have known* Q would have these. :-)

Comment: @Bergi, "But notice that with these solutions you need to ensure that count and findAll are called with zero arguments". Could you explain this ?

Comment: @Bergi, Everything other than `Q.ninvoke` doesn't give me the result.

Comment: @espeirasbora: When you "bind" the function, and you call `findAll(x, y)`, then Q will call `User.find({}, x, y, function(err, res) {…})` - which is not going to work. So you always have to call `findAll()` only.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** Q has a built-in version of the below, so if you're using Q (as the OP is), see [Bergi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33364215/157247). If you're using some other promise lib, see if it does; if not, see below.

---

You can give yourself a utility function that wraps Node-style calls and turns them into promises (but keep reading), so:

```
count: function() {
  return makePromise(User.count)
}
```

`makePromise` would look something like

```
function makePromise(f) {
  var deferred = Q.defer()
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
  args[0] = function(err) {
    if(err)
      deferred.reject(err)
    else
      deferred.resolve(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1))
  }
  f.apply(null, args)
  return deferred.promise
}
```

*(I'm trying to follow your convention of leaving off `;` that ASI will correct)*

That calls the function you gave it, passing along any further arguments, and when it gets the response either rejects the promise using `err`, or resolves it using an array of the arguments it got after `err`. Could be used with all Node-style functions that call their callbacks with `err` as the first argument.

**But**, someone's already done that for you: [`promisify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify) :-) I'm fairly sure there's at least one other one as well.

A slightly more complex version would support optionally giving a `thisArg` up front:

```
function makePromise(obj, f) {
  var deferred = Q.defer()
  var args, func, thisArg;
  if (typeof obj === "function") {
    thisArg = null
    func = obj
    args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
  } else {
    thisArg = obj
    func = f
    args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)
  }
  args[0] = function(err) {
    if(err)
      deferred.reject(err)
    else
      deferred.resolve(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1))
  }
  func.apply(thisArg, args)
  return deferred.promise
}
```

Then if `User.count` needs to be called with `this` = `User`:

```
count: function() {
  return makePromise(User, User.count)
}
```